# How to get an entity OF an entity in core data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a data model set up like this:

`Entity 1` >> (one-to-many) >> `Entity 2` >> (one-to-many) >> `Entity 3`

Now in one of my view controllers, I have a property of `Entity 2*`, which is an object. How can I access `Entity 3` OF a particular instance of `Entity 2`? I've tried using:

`fetchRequestWithEntityName:`, but I don't want to get a dump of every single one of `Entity 3`s, just all the `Entity 3` belonging to an instance of `Entity 2`.

Thanks much for any help!

~Carpetfizz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the relationship:

```
Entity2 *e2 = ... // Your Entity2 object
NSSet *e3s = e2.entity3s;
// or:
NSArray *e3s = [e2.entity3s allObjects];
```

assuming that the to-many relationship from `Entity2` to `Entity3` is called "entity3s".

If you need a fetch request (e.g. for a fetched results controller), then
you just have to add a predicate:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity3"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entity2 = %@", e2];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

assuming that the inverse to-one relationship from `Entity3` to `Entity2`
is called "entity2".